# GridView: convert data before bindind to GridView

Tags: asp.net

My GridView using following data binding syntax to bind data. 
I hope do data conversion before it is really bound to GridView. For example, **if the VendorID int property (I use a List as data source) is 0, I wish showing empty string on that field.** 
What kind of event I could exploit? And if you could suggest any code sample?

Thanks a lot.

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vendor ID">
            <ItemStyle Width="1%" BorderColor="#efefef" BorderWidth="1px" />
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblNo" Text='<%# Bind("VendorID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle BorderColor="#efefef" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gridview's RowDataBound Event can be use for this.

```
void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {

    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      // do wat ever u like to do here. 
      // formating, checking, changing data, etc....

      e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "<i>" + e.Row.Cells[1].Text + "</i>";

    }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

hi you can use following code in **RowDataboundEvent**

```
  if (DataBinder.Eval(args.Row.DataItem, "VendorID").ToString() == "0")
    {
        ((Label)args.Row.FindControl("lblNo")).Text = "";
    }
    else
    {
        ((Label)args.Row.FindControl("lblNo")).Text = DataBinder.Eval(args.Row.DataItem, "VendorID").ToString();
    }
```